# ssh from linux vm to windows vm to run power shell using python

Tags: python, linux, powershell, ssh, virtual-machine

I am trying to connect to Windows VM (On-Premises) from Linux VM (created from Azure) to run PowerShell command using SSH in python program

Python Code:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ('connecting')
ssh.connect(hostname='WindowsVMIPAddress', username='WindowsVMusername', password='WindowsVMpassword')
print('connected')
```

Error:

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

What I am trying to achieve:
Using python program, want to ssh from Linux VM (azure) to Windows VM to run the powerShell script. Any other suggestions, how I can achieve this?

Comment: `on-premise` to me suggests a corporate environment. This leads me to two questions, neither of which have to do with **programming**.  a) Is your organisation firewalled? Talk to your security people.  b) Does your windows VM actually have a publicly routable IP address?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think windows VM is not publicly routable as it is inside organization network. in that case, it is not possible to connect?

Comment: You're welcome, and it depends on whether or not your network/security people would be willing to set-up a dedicated forwarded port to the inside.  I'd be surprised if they did, but it's not out of the question.  Personally I'd try to go the other way, maybe establish a reverse ssh proxy connection from the Windows Box into the Azure instance ... but that would really be a topic for [su] **or** [sf] ...